# JQuery href preventdefault issue with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, href, preventdefault

I have a link as following.

```
<a href="#" id="tab3Link">Tab 3</a>
```

On tab 2, when **Tab 3** is clicked, I want to first validate whether form in Tab 2 is correctly filled.

```
    $("#tab3Link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab3Link").prop("href", "#");
            if(validateTab2()){
                $("#tab3Link").prop("href", "#tab3Info");
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
    });
```

`#tab3Info` anchor should take the page to a new div. But click does not happen. But if I manually append `#tab3Info` at the end of the URL and press enter, page moves to new tab. So in the above function, although href is changed, click function does not happen.

This is working fine when JQuery 1.4.2 is used with Jquery mobile 1.1.0. Problem occurs when JQuery was upgraded to 1.9.1 and Jquery mobile to 1.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of return true, try:

```
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage of jQuery `prop()` method does not apply since it sets a property in the element (in your case #tab3Link). But you want to manipulate the location value.

Instead of:

```
$("#tab3Link").prop("href", "#tab3Info");
```

You can either use:

```
window.location.hash  = 'tab3Info';
```

or:

```
window.location += '#tab3Info';
```

Comment: in the previos version of the code, $("#tab3Link").attr("href", "#tab3Info"); was being used. It was not working with the jquery upgrade I mentioned in the question. That's why I replaced attr with prop. Still it did not work. siracoj's answer worked. I will try this one too.